# Reasons to use localized version of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, localization

What reasons to use localized version of Visual Studio 2010? What problems / benefits can you list while using localized versions? Are localized versions really useful?

Answer (score 2):

I can only see problems and very few benefits. Any problems you are likely to experience you will will get them in language other then English, which means searching how to resolve problem in that language is limited on start. Although it may be not directly related but I've been managing servers in polish language for a long time and man I was so many times wishing the errors by polish system was in English. Finding resolution to problems in English is 50x easier then in my native tongue. If you even try to translate error message yourself you will have to be very careful because one translation isn't equal to another, especially when it comes to Microsoft  programs (although not only). Many times error in my language given by SharePoint or Windows is so meaningless that you don't even know where to start looking for answers and if you see that error in English you just do "Oh.. it's about this.. simple stuff. Lets fix it".

Back to development.. Visual Studio in English gives you no problems to develop programs for any language you want. And most likely any addons will be in English so you will have mixed environment at some point having one Menu in English and other one in German. Also asking for help and following some tutorials/tips etc will be far easier in English so you won't have to translate stuff On-The-Fly yourself but will just follow the steps.